# Split code to some vars

Tags: php, regex, var

sorry for any mistake i am beginner on php 
i got this value and want split  the usa address  from the code

```
Service Address

GERTRUDE HAGAMAN 
 2608 N LAKEVIEW DR
HAMMONTON, NJ 08037-3501 

Manage XFINITY WiFi 
Manage Xfinity wifi home hotspot setting
```

i need extract  to be

```
$name :    GERTRUDE HAGAMAN 
$address : 2608 N LAKEVIEW DR
$city    : HAMMONTON
$state   : NJ 
$zipcode : 08037-3501
```

so is there any advice

Comment: You could split the text by lines (`\r\n`) into an array and then parse the address lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match('/service address\n*(.*)\n*(.*)\n((.*?),\s+(\w{2})\s+(.*))\n*manage xfinity wifi/i', $full_address, $match);

$name = $match[1];
$address = $match[2];
$city = $match[4];
$state = $match[5];
$zip = $match[6];
?>
```

this will only work if the address format is similar to what you have posted above

Comment: thanks for your reply 

i got this

Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g' in /home/comcast/public_html/camcast/next.php on line 31

Name : 
Address : 
city  : 
state  : 
zipcode : 
data not shown with this error

Comment: Sorry, there is no modifier g for prey_match function it is for prey_match_all function, just remove the g. I updated the answer